# Threads writing to a buffer memory and thread memory

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Let's imagine you have a multi-threaded running program. In my case the program uses std::thread but this is not important I suppose. Now each thread needs to write into some global buffer, but they are guaranteed to never write to the same memory address in this buffer. Questions:

- is it thread safe?
- is it efficient? I mean by that, if you have 8 threads they may access different parts of this buffer memory. This probably causes a lot of cache misses?

The code above is just an example of what I mean by "the threads write to the same buffer but never at the same address" (though the buffer is much bigger in my case and threads access very different part of that buffer).

```
int *buffer = new buffer[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    threads[k] = std::thread(threadFunc, std::ref(buffer), i);
}

void threadFunc(int *&buffer, const int &threadId)
{
    buffer[threadId] = threadId;
}
```

Comment: Its definitely safe, but you have a good point about parts of the cache possibly being re-loaded for each thread in turn. I suppose that you need to do some timing tests. I suppose you could arrange for all the threads to be closely bound by memory address, ensuring all threads finish processing one (segregated) chunk before allowing them all to move on to the next (segregated) chunk. Sounds a bit complicated though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multithreaded access creates undefined behavior (a race condition, or worse) if two threads perform a conflicting access without synchronization.

Two accesses to the *same memory location* conflict.  Access to separate array elements are safe.

In the Standard, 1.7p3 says that

> A memory location is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having non-zero width. [ Note: Various features of the language, such as references and virtual functions, might involve additional memory locations that are not accessible to programs but are managed by the implementation. — end note ] Two or more threads of execution (1.10) can update and access separate memory locations without interfering with each other.

However, it probably won't be efficient.  If multiple array elements fit into a single cache line, then the threads are going to fight over ownership.  This is called ["false sharing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing), and basically negates the performance advantages of having cache in the first place.  To overcome this, it may be necessary to add padding so that different array elements exist in different cache lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot and thx for mentioning padding. Wouldn't another solution be to let each thread have its own local cache and then lock the buffer in the end and write to the main buffer?

Comment: @user18490: Yes, that works if the per-thread data is never ever shared.  Padding works well when cross-thread access happens but infrequently.

Comment: "If multiple array elements fit into a single cache line, then the threads are going to fight over ownership." – False sharing only occurs if a second hardware thread *accesses* a memory location that's on the first hardware thread's cache. Just because the element size is less than the cache line size doesn't mean there's *automatically* false sharing. (I assume you meant that, you may want to clarify your answer.)

Comment: @ArneVogel: It's true that there are degenerate cases (one hardware thread context switching between all software threads, or exactly two threads and the array happens to straddle the cache line boundary), but the question clearly is talking about each array element being written by a different thread, so that "multiple array elements fit into a single cache line" is the condition under which "a thread accesses a memory location that's on another thread's cache" will occur.

Answer (score 0):

> ...but they are guaranteed to never write to the same memory address in
>   this buffer

This makes it thread safe. Reads would be efficient, but writes might create cache contention on some architectures.

However, the buffer would have to be rather big, because thread-ids are normally in the hundreds. You can't use a strategy like a map without synchronization, so due to the sparseness, you'd have to use a sparse array like `buffer[12]` and `buffer[134]`, etc. Unless you are assigning an ID of your own to each thread, which requires state in each thread... this idea is superseded by what I have below.

The best strategy is generally to have the stack of each thread hold a pointer to the static memory location and pass this context around as an argument to the various functions within the thread that need it. This is why context objects are so useful in multi-threaded programming.

Comment: "the writes would be perfectly efficient" -- no, there can be cache contention due to false sharing

Comment: Why would that cause contention? It should have a different view of the same cache line in each thread.

Comment: Because [a write requires the cache line to first be in "Exclusive" or "Modified"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol#Read_For_Ownership) state, it can't be cached in multiple threads at once.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: On a multi-core system, there is per-core caching anyway. Each core has its own L1 and L2 cache. The problem you're describing only makes sense if the two threads are sharing the same L1 cache.

Comment: The problem I'm describing occurs exactly when there are multiple L1 caches.  A write on one core evicts that cache line from all other caches.

Comment: Does it really work as described in that MESI protocol, on modern processors? Why doesn't it let the view from the other thread go stale for a while until it can't anymore (e.g. a memory barrier is set up)? I always imagined the per-core caches containing differing state.

Comment: Then when both caches eventually flush, one would obliterate all the writes made by the other.  The C++ memory model doesn't allow that to happen (on hardware that worked that way, a C++ compiler would have to add barriers everywhere)

Comment: And while modern processors may not use MESI, they do use its variants.  For example, Wikipedia describes [MESIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESIF_protocol) and the fact that the Nehalem generation of Intel Core i CPUs uses it.

Comment: Write-combining would prevent the obliteration problem you're talking about. But if they aren't really doing that it's a moot point. I'll look into MESIF.

Comment: With store buffers (the mechanism that makes write combining work), execution shouldn't be blocked waiting for exclusive access to the cache line, so as you say, the performance hit won't be as bad -- until you hit a barrier on any other variable, or have reads mixed in with the writes, or run out of store buffer due to other variables.  I think your analysis is correct, just not your terminology (multiple cores can have writes pending to parts of the same cache line in their *store buffers*, but not have the full cache line in more than one cache)